# Do people not like my red, glowing scars?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm swimming in the deep end of the Renegade pool, and I've got the red, glowing scars to prove it. I can understand that people may dislike or fear me due to my chaotic decisions, but physical discrimination crosses the line!

**Does my unsavory appearance affect the dispositions or conversations I have with other characters?**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is Mass Effect 3? It's hard to remember, but that looks more like the alignment display from ME1.

Comment: I think you're right. I've updated the image. Thanks.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Shows how much you know.  That's a ME2 alignment display! ;)

Comment: @CaulynDarr It's been a while since I played ME1 or ME2. I just knew it wasn't from ME3 :)

Comment: I'm not sure it makes sense to consider your appearance separately from its cause.  Seems like a contrived question, honestly.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. In previous Bioware games, alignment, karma, paragon/regenade, etc. did have an influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your physical appearance has no effect on available choices or actions. Someone will sleep with you even if you look like that. The game characters know its that Paragon or Renegade gushing heart what matters. Also unlike ME2, ME3 conversvation choices are dependent on the SUM of Paragon, Renegade, and reputation points.

This differs from previous Bioware games such as KOTR where your alignment (Good / Paragon vs Evil / Renegade) do affect relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices matter, but your appearance doesn't. Go ahead and bed everyone you want to, just be aware it might be a little harder when they dislike some of your decisions.

Answer (score 1):

No, your choices and reputation make a difference, but no one seems to mind the scars.  Not even your love interest straight or otherwise; just to go ahead and answer your next question for you :)